# How to insert sidebarLayout/sidebarPanel in shiny dashboard?

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I've been creating a shiny app and now I want to reproduce it in shiny dashboard without success so far. My main question is if sidebarLayout/sidebarPanel works inside dashboardSidebar? I'm having this error message: Expected an object with class 'shiny.tag'. Does anyone know what is this error about? Thanks a lot!!

Here is my ui.R

```
ui = dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title="Deteccao de arvores individuais de LiDAR em Shiny App - R", align="center"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Defina seus parametros e preferencias")),
    sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
       fileInput('layer', 'Select the CHM.asc file', multiple=FALSE, accept='asc', width = "350px"),
      selectInput("fws", "Select the size of windows to find trees", choices = c("3x3"= (fws<-3), "5x5"= (fws<-5), "7x7"= (fws<-7)), width = "350px"),
       wellPanel(checkboxInput("checkbox", "Would you like to apply the smoothing model for canopy?", value = FALSE, width = "350px"), selectInput("sws", "Select the size of the smoothing window for trees", choices = c("3x3" = (sws<-3), "5x5" = (sws<-5), "7x7"=(sws<-7)), width = "350px")),
       checkboxInput("checkp", "Plot individual trees detected in CHM", value=FALSE, width="350px"),
       checkboxInput("checkpd", "Download the shapefile (.shp) of Individual trees detected", value = FALSE, width = "350px"), uiOutput("shapefile"),
       actionButton("action", "RUN!")))

      ),

  dashboardBody( 
    fluidRow( 
      tabBox(side="right", height = "500px", 
                tabPanel("Visualization of CHM", plotOutput("mapPlot")),
                tabPanel("Trees detected from rLiDAR", tableOutput("arvlist"), downloadButton("downList", "Download Tree List")),
                tabPanel("Summary of LiDAR metrics", tableOutput("sumy"), downloadButton("downSumy", "Download Summary of LiDAR metrics")),
                tabPanel("Profile of height model", plotOutput("hist"), downloadButton("downHist", "Download Height's Histogram of Density")), #histograma de densidade
                tabPanel("Individual trees detected - Model 2D of CHM", plotOutput("plotTrees"), downloadButton("downDetec", "Download CHM of Trees Detected"))


                 )


    ))
  )
```

Comment: This is error is due to the argument `align="center"` in your `dashboardHeader()` just remove that argument and the error should be sorted out.

Comment: Hey. I removed that and now I'm having the ERROR: argument "mainPanel" is missing, with no default. I read that sidebarLayout() needs to include the mainPanel(). My issue is that I don't know how to insert the sidebar in the dashboard, cause I've just seen it be embedded as "menu". Do you know how to solve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: As far as I can understand you want all of the object ts to appear in the dashboard sidebar. Why don't you remove the `sidebarLayout` and `sidebarPanel` and try it. By default it will just occupy the dashboard sidebar.

Comment: Oh, I worked @SBista! Thanks a lot!